# Calendar with highlighted date in java script or jquery or angularjs 1.x

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I calendar with highlighted date for persons who mark the date. there are list of person who are on leave on that date.

angular js 1.x

small jquery or angular js library

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of things you can use here:

The jqueryUI package still has this bad boy running https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

or depending if you are using a css framework you could use one of the datepickers there like https://materializecss.com/

https://fullcalendar.io/ --> this might be too advanced depending on your needs